# How to implement this constraint in gurobi via python API

Tags: python, linear-programming, gurobi

I have a constraint to be implemented in Gurobi using Python API. B and A are decision variables.
The constraint is defined as :
[image]
Relevant code looks like this :

```
for r in R:
    for (u, v) in R[r][1][0]:
        for x in X:
            sfcModel.addConstr(
            quicksum(B[r-1, u, v, x, y]*A[r-1, u, x]*A[r-1, v, y] for y in X and y!=x ) == 1 ,"src_constraint")
```

Getting this error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/project/ilp.py", line 400, in <module>
    quicksum(B[r-1, u, v, x, y] for y in X and y!=x ) == 1 ,"src_constraint"
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

Any one can help me to fix it ? 
Thanks

Comment: That's a basic python problem: probably one of ```R```, ```R[r][1][0]``` or ```X``` is a bool. (maybe something wrong within quicksum; but debugging looks the same: call type(x) on everything which is used). By the way: the **full** stack-trace probably tells you exactly which var is boolean, but for some reason you keep us guessing ;-) (i'm writing something like that for 50% of all python-questions here...)

Comment: @sascha I edited the question with the complete error trace.

Comment: That does noot look like valid python (probably at least non-expected results). So you are trying to do a list comprehension here, right? **And if B and A are variables; this is not gonna work anyway** (convexity!).

Comment: @sascha A and B are decision variables, I edited the question and put a correct formulation of the constraint. I am trying to make a list comprehension but as I have to fix one index and vary the other one I though to do it as written. I am not sure where is the issue.

Comment: That's basic python (a list-comprehension looks different to me)... But it does not matter... You won't be able to formulate it like that (or at least not be able to solve it; so fixing this is wasted time). This will need re-formulation and therefore probably some experience with this.

Comment: What I wanted to formulate is as follow : for each pair of edges (u,v) allocate a link (x,y) where the endpoint u is placed starting from x. But as you suggest not wasting time to fix it as is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157157/discussion-between-user2567806-and-sascha).